# Accessing resources in vscode previewHtml with file scheme

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my vscode extension how do I link to resources like scripts when displaying a static html page with [`vscode.previewHtml`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands#_working-with-the-html-preview)?

For example, I'm doing,

```
let uri = Uri.parse(`file:///${__dirname}/file.html`);
let success = await commands.executeCommand('vscode.previewHtml', uri);
```

And in `file.html` I have,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
  Content
  <!-- <how do I know path/to/extension below ? > -->
  <script src="file:///path/to/extension/my_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I know what should be`path/to/extension` ?

What I am doing currently is registering a content provider for a different scheme and generating this html with js. (a virtual resource). I would like to know if there is a way I can avoid that and just use file scheme.

Answer (score 3):

In [my extension](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/frontend/ATNGraphProvider.ts#L39) the html file is filled with markers I can replace in the extension code, including paths to resources like other scripts, CSS files and images.

For file references I use this function, which concatenates the extension folder and a `misc` folder (where I keep these additional files) to create the absolute target path for a resource:

```
/**
 * Returns the absolute path to a file located in our misc folder.
 *
 * @param file The base file name.
 * @param context The context of this extension to get its path regardless where it is installed.
 */
public static getMiscPath(file: string, context: ExtensionContext, asUri = false): string {
    if (asUri) {
        return Uri.file(context.asAbsolutePath(path.join('misc', file))).toString();
    }
    return Uri.file(context.asAbsolutePath(path.join('misc', file))).fsPath;
}
```

That path can then be set in the HTML skeleton.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. There's a lot I can learn from your plugin. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Hi Mike, your extension is amazing work. I've read through the code a lot last night and today and I have some questions, as I'm trying to port an Electron app I have into a VSCode extension, where the Electron app does nothing special with Electron and just uses yarn/npm packages inside some typescript/javascript files. 

In creating the HTML to open my webview, I use many third party libraries like request, jquery-ui, jquery, etc. With d3 in your example, you have it in your package.json, but also explicitly send d3 as a script url in the html? I'll ask more on your github.